# How to display a Spark TextArea component as a child of a MovieClip

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, textarea, movieclip

I need to use a TextArea in my application as it supports the TLF framework and allow edition of the text by the user.

My problem is that this TextArea has to be the child of a MovieClip, but I can't make it work and the TextArea is not displayed.

Here is a sample of my code:

```
var mc:UIMovieClip = new UIMovieClip();
mc.graphics.clear();
mc.graphics.lineStyle(2, 0, 1);
mc.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 400, 300);
mc.width = 400;
mc.height = 300;

var textArea:TextArea = new TextArea();
textArea.width = 350;
textArea.height = 250;
textArea.text = "Hello world!";
mc.addChild(textArea);
myCanvas.rawChildren.addChild(mc);
```

The TextArea component is displayed correctly when I add the TextArea directly as a child of the canvas, i.e when I replace the line

```
mc.addChild(textArea);
```

with the following

```
mainCanvas.addChild(mc);
```

The reason why the TextArea needs to be a child of a MovieClip is that I'm using a external library working with MovieClips.
The trick doesn't work either if I use a UIMovieClip instead of the MovieClip.

Can someone explain why a TextArea would not be displayed in that sort of situation?
Is there any workaround to obtain the desired result? (I tried to use a UIComponent as an intermediate child without success)

Comment: Assuming you mean a Flex `mx.controls.TextArea`, that cannot be added to a UIMovieClip.  Perhaps you could elaborate more on your ultimate goal including how this external library is called using the `MovieClip`.  Also, what version of Flex are you using?  Flex 3 `mx:Canvas` could be replaced by Flex 4 `s:SpriteVisualElement`.

Comment: I'm talking of a Flex `spark.components.TextArea` component and I'm using Flex 4.5. The problem has nothing to do with the `Canvas` as it works fine when the `TextArea` is directly added as a child of it.
The library used handles shapes that can be user generated as long as they are an instance of `MovieClip`. In this case, I want to pass it a shape containing an editable text area and handling texts written from right to left. That's the reason why I want to use the Spark `TextArea` class with the property `direction`. Hope it can help!

Comment: `spark.components.TextArea` cannot be added to a UIMovieClip.  UIMovieClip class implements the interfaces necessary for a Flash component to be used like a normal Flex component.  It does not enable Flex components to be added as children of the UIMovieClip.  Spark's `s:SpriteVisualElement` is a nice replacement to Halo's `mx:Canvas`.  If you're trying to merge controls from Flash Pro, you could use `fl.controls.TextArea`.

Comment: Does that mean that I have no other choice but using manually a `TextFlow` and a `ContainerController` in that case? (both are part of the `flashx.textLayout` package)

Comment: If this library only needs the geometry of the TextArea, you could first add the TextArea, then overlay a MovieClip above the TextArea setting `mouseEnabled=false` and `mouseChildren=false`.  This way, the TextArea underneath the MovieClip would remain interactive and the library could still perform rendering on the MovieClip.

Comment: The library will handle user interactions such as drag to move the given `MovieClip` so the TextArea has to be part of it.
In case I can ask an update of the library, what other class could substitute to MovieClip and allow a Flex component to be added as its child?

Comment: @JasonSturges Is it not possible to add the TextArea to a `s:SpriteVisualElement` and then add that to the MovieClip?

Comment: @RIAstar OP wants `s:TextArea` as a child of `MovieClip` on the display list.  `s:SpriteVisualElement` base would `Sprite`. Adding SpriteVisualElement to a MovieClip seems like it would not receive layout, and should throw LayoutManager errors. It's a good idea, though - may satisfy the need.

Comment: @RIAstar I gave a try to your solution but with no more success : the TextArea won't be displayed, unless I'm doing something wrong...

Answer (score 0):

If the `MovieClip` you are using was compiled from Flash, one nice solution we have been using a lot recently is to actually export it as Flex-friendly container :
http://www.webkitchen.be/2009/02/11/video-tutorial-create-flex-container-components-with-flash-cs4/

If not, try extending `ContainerMovieClip` instead of `UIMovieClip`, and setting its `content` property.